# How can I determine if a transformation is onto

Tags: linear-algebra

Is (x,y) mapped into (x,y,0) an onto transformation? If I use the theorem that the dimension of V is less than the dimension of W, then I think that it's not onto. However, I don't see a vector in W that doesn't have a pre-image in V.

Comment: It depends on what exactly $V$ and $W$ are.  The map $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ which maps $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,0)$ looks like the transformation you are talking about.  In which case, is there any preimage for something in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where the third coordinate is nonzero?  (e.g. $(1,1,1)$).  In the case that your $W$ is something like $V\times\{0\}$, then it would be onto (since in that case all elements in $W$ have zero as a third entry).

Comment: The third entry in W is zero. It's (x,y,zero).

Comment: You misunderstand, a function, $f:~V\to W$, (or transformation for that matter) is a map from a **Domain** $V$ to a **Codomain** $W$ (presumably here the domain is $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and the codomain is $W=\mathbb{R}^3$).  The **range** on the other hand is the image of the map.  Only when the range is equal to the codomain is the function considered **onto**.  The third entry in $W$ is not necessarily always zero if $W=\mathbb{R}^3$ in which case $(1,1,1)$ doesn't have a preimage.  If $W=\mathbb{R}^2\times\{0\}$, then you are correct that every element has a zero as the third entry.

Comment: @JMoravitz Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).